# Kendo Grid Row Filter

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have implemented Kendo Grid for displaying data. I am facing a problem while filtering any column. 
For example if I filter the "name" column in the grid with "Is Not Empty" or "Is Not Null" both the rows are appearing in the grid as filtered result.

// Both rows from datasource

```
1.  { id: 1, name: "  ", age: 30 },
2.  { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
```

But i need to have only one row as filtered result, as "name" in the first record contains white spaces.

```
2.  { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
```

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "age" }
    ],
    dataSource: {
      data: [
        { id: 1, name: "  ", age: 30 },
        { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
      ],
      schema: {
        model: { id: "id" }
      }
    },
    filterable: true

  });
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to define a custom filter operator and not using the default "is not null".

Here are some attempts to do it https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-define-a-custom-filter-operator

Basically you need to create a custom function to filter kendo.DataSource. Hope the link helps